# How can I write method with question mark using define_method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, metaprogramming

I have user model that has many types (admin, normal, ..). And I make loop to define methods like `admin?` or `normal?` as the following:

```
class User
  TYPES = %w(admin normal)
  User::TYPES.each do |roleVal|
    define_method(roleVal.to_sym) { self.role == roleVal }
  end
end
```

The above code is working for example `User.first.admin`, But I need to call it as `User.first.admin?`.

What's the syntax of [define_method](http://apidock.com/ruby/Module/define_method) with question mark ? 
And if that's not possible using `define_method`, How to create methods with question mark in meta-programming ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you want is this:

```
define_method("#{roleVal}?") { ... }
```

Answer (score 3):

It's pretty straightforward to define this kind of method with `define_method`. It's enough to pass symbol or string that ends with the question mark.

```
define_method(:admin?) do
  # code
end
```

Comment: Yeah, it's little bit unclear, because according to the documentation for [`define_method`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Module.html#method-i-define_method), it use a symbol as argument.

Comment: True. But the symbol can end with `?` as well.

Comment: @Зелёный Yes, the docs sometimes use symbols where they are not strictly necessary. If you look at the C code of `define_method`, you'll see that `rb_to_id` is called on the name, which turns strings, fixnums and symbols into the MRI `ID` type. At the very end `ID2SYM(id)` is called, which turns the `ID` value into a Ruby symbol (the return value of `define_methdod`).

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing special in the *ending question mark* within symbols:

```
class User
  TYPES = %i(admin? normal?)
  User::TYPES.each do |roleVal|
    define_method(roleVal) { self.role == roleVal.to_s[0...-1] }
  end 
end
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do as below.

```
class User
  TYPES = %w(admin normal)
  User::TYPES.each do |roleVal|
    define_method("#{roleVal}?") do self.role == roleVal end
  end
end
```

Hope, this will help you.

Comment: Why you need `to_sym` here?

Comment: It's the same, and it's a bad for readability use `do ... end` in one line.